# I cannot validate a double against a list of doubles in a grails 'inList'

Tags: validation, grails

I'm new to grails, so I hope not to embarrass myself with an oversight on my part, but I've experimented with this problem twice and experienced a consistent failure of 'inList' to validate from a list of doubles.  I looked for a prior report of this problem and could find one.  So here it is:

I wanted to validate a field of type double against a list of acceptable doubles with the inList constraint.  The scaffold-generated logic does display properly the list of doubles on the webpage using a g:select.  When I selected any of the valid doubles from the pulldown list, the 'inList' validation in the domain class rejects them.  For example, if I selected '2.0' from the pulldown list, I get this error message on the webpage:

Property [aFloat] of class [class demo2.FloatsOkInList] with value [2] is not contained within the list [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]]

Ok, I can see that '2.0' has been striped back to '2', so during the round trip my submission may have been either formatted for display or converted into an Integer or String. But my code has not done this transformation.  My controller is pure template that I haven't modified.  My domain code is this:

```
 class FloatsOkInList {
    String aKey
    Double aFloat
    static constraints = {
        aKey unique : true, blank : false
        aFloat blank : false , inList :[ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
    }
}
```

The view generates a field that looks like this:

```
<g:select name="aFloat" from="${floatsOkInListInstance.constraints.aFloat.inList}" required="" value="${fieldValue(bean: floatsOkInListInstance, field: 'aFloat')}" valueMessagePrefix="floatsOkInList.aFloat"/>
```

I don't think it's unreasonable to expect 'inList' to validate against a list of doubles.

APPLICATION STATUS
App version: 0.1
Grails version: 2.2.1
Groovy version: 2.0.7
JVM version: 1.7.0_01
Reloading active: true
Controllers: 2
Domains: 1
...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1.0` is by default `BigDecimal`.
`[ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]` is a list of BigDecimal.
`Double` will not be found in the above list.

`assert !1.0D in [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]`

Use
`inList: [1D, 2D, 3D, 4D]` 
or 
`inList: (1..4)*.toDouble()`

in the constraints instead.

Comment: Thanks for a very satisfying solution.  During my effort to deal with the validation problem, I wrote a custom validator which had this in it:  [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0]find{ ot -> ot.equals(itt) }  I couldn't understand why it was failing.  Isn't this just another manifestation of the your solution: [<BigDecimal list>]{ <BigDecimal>.equals(<some double>)} ?  Incidentally, this closure did work for me when I substituted 'ot == itt' for 'ot.equals(itt)'.  So, "==" must be more tolerant of different data types on left and right?

Comment: Good question if you have recently started using Groovy/Grails. Refer [Groovy Common Gotchas](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Differences+from+Java) to get your answer. Summary: In Groovy `==` means `equals()`. I bet you will enjoy the read.